# NameError using LinearRegression() with python API

Tags: google-cloud-datalab, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to run some regressions in Earth Engine using Cloud Datalab. When I replicate the code in [this regression tutorial](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_regression) (modifying it for python), I get this error:

```
NameErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-21c9bd377408> in <module>()
     14 linearRegression = collection.reduce(
     15   ee.Reducer.linearRegression({
---> 16     numX: 2,
     17     numY: 2
     18 }))

NameError: name 'numX' is not defined
```

This does not seem to be an issue for other functions, and the same code works in the Javascript API. Is LinearRegression used differently in the python API?

Comment: did you try setting `numX` and `numY` between quotes?

Comment: Yeah, I did - that yields a different error: `EEException: Invalid argument specified for ee.Number(): {'numX': 2, 'numY': 2}`. However, Rodrigo's solution below works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arguments as python keyword arguments, like this:

```
import ee
ee.Initialize()

# This function adds a time band to the image.
def createTimeBand(image):
  # Scale milliseconds by a large constant.
  return image.addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start').divide(1e18))

# This function adds a constant band to the image.
def createConstantBand(image):
  return ee.Image(1).addBands(image)

# Load the input image collection: projected climate data.
collection = (ee.ImageCollection('NASA/NEX-DCP30_ENSEMBLE_STATS')
  .filterDate(ee.Date('2006-01-01'), ee.Date('2099-01-01'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('scenario', 'rcp85'))
  # Map the functions over the collection, to get constant and time bands.
  .map(createTimeBand)
  .map(createConstantBand)
  # Select the predictors and the responses.
  .select(['constant', 'system:time_start', 'pr_mean', 'tasmax_mean']))

# Compute ordinary least squares regression coefficients.
linearRegression = (collection.reduce(
  ee.Reducer.linearRegression(
    numX= 2,
    numY= 2
)))

# Compute robust linear regression coefficients.
robustLinearRegression = (collection.reduce(
  ee.Reducer.robustLinearRegression(
    numX= 2,
    numY= 2
)))

# The results are array images that must be flattened for display.
# These lists label the information along each axis of the arrays.
bandNames = [['constant', 'time'], # 0-axis variation.
                 ['precip', 'temp']] # 1-axis variation.

# Flatten the array images to get multi-band images according to the labels.
lrImage = linearRegression.select(['coefficients']).arrayFlatten(bandNames)
rlrImage = robustLinearRegression.select(['coefficients']).arrayFlatten(bandNames)

# Print to check it works
print rlrImage.getInfo(), lrImage.getInfo()
```

I have not checked the results, but there are no errors, the images are created.

Comment: Thanks! Worked well.

Comment: Hey Andrew, if you are using the python API you could want to have a look at https://github.com/gee-community/gee_tools